# Determining if ArcGIS Operations Dashboard down

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard, coronavirus

Is the [Coronavirus COVID-19 Global Cases by the Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6) dashboard down?

Answer (score 2):

GIS StackExchange is not really the correct place to ask this sort of "place-in-time" question.

To check on the status of a particular webservice you should start with the hosting website. In this particular case, you know the service is hosted on ArcGIS.com. A good source to check would be the Status website:  http://status.arcgis.com/

Specifically for this app you've question, hosted feature services did encounter problems today (March 12, 2020) which may impact the uptime of the particular application you're asking about.

Additionally, the authors of the John Hopkins dashboard have a github site that they appear to respond to: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Comment: Thanks I have heard of a lot of people reporting fake sites for the JH arcgis dashboard, good to know this is not the appropriate place to ask.